# Enumerate lazily until the block is false

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I've written an Enumerable class to seamlessly and lazily fetch all pages of an API request.

```
class Pager
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(&fetch_next_page)
    @fetch_next_page = fetch_next_page
    reset
  end

  def reset
    @page_number = 0
  end

  private def next_page
    @page_number += 1

    return @fetch_next_page.call(@page_number)
  end

  def each(&block)
    if block_given?
      while resp = next_page
        resp.each(&block)
      end
      reset
    else
      to_enum(:each)
    end
  end
end
```

Here's an example of how it might be used.

```
pager = Pager.new do |page_number|
  response = fetch_page( page: page_number, **some_options )

  response.page <= response.total_pages ? response.stuff : false
end
```

But I've come to realize all this is doing is executing a block that returns an Enumerable until its false, and it's flattening the Enumerables.

```
pager = Pager.new { |page_number|
  page_number <= 3 ? 1.upto(page_number) : false
}

# [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
puts pager.to_a.inspect
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? I've come close with Enumerator, but can't get the flattening to work.

```
def paginate(&fetch_next)
  return Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    page_number = 1
    while ret = fetch_next.call(page_number)
      yielder.yield(*ret)
      page_number += 1
    end
  end
end

pager = paginate { |page_number|
  page_number <= 3 ? 1.upto(page_number) : false
}

# [1, [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
puts pager.to_a.inspect
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the output for the enumerator isn't correct has indeed to do with the splat operator.

If you pass multiple values to *yield* they are yielded all at once, whereas you'd like to yield them one by one. Since you've got the block:

```
{ |page_number| page_number <= 3 ? 1.upto(page_number) : false }
```

This will result in 3 yields. The first with arguments `1`, the second with arguments `1, 2` and the third with arguments `1, 2, 3`. If you'd like to yield them as individual yields you'll have to change the following:

```
yielder.yield(*ret)

# should be changed to

ret.each { |e| yielder.yield e }
# or
ret.each { |e| yielder << e }
# depending on your preference
```

```
pager.to_a
#=> [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```